# Slicing a Python OrderedDict

Tags: python-2.7, slice, ordereddictionary

In my code I frequently need to take a subset range of keys+values from a Python `OrderedDict` (from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) package). Slicing doesn't work (throws `TypeError: unhashable type`) and the alternative, iterating, is cumbersome:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

o = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])

# want to do:
# x = o[1:3]
# need to do:
x = OrderedDict()
for idx, key in enumerate(o):
    if 1 <= idx < 3:
        x[key] = o[key]
```

Is there a better way to get this done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ordered dict in the standard library, doesn't provide that functionality. Even though libraries existed for a few years before collections.OrderedDict that have this functionality (and provide essentially a superset of OrderedDict): [voidspace odict](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html) and [ruamel.ordereddict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.ordereddict) (I am the author of the latter package, which is a reimplementation of odict in C):

```
from odict import OrderedDict as odict
p = odict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
print p[1:3]
```

In ruamel.ordereddict you can relax the ordered input requirement (AFAIK you cannot ask derivative of dict if its keys are ordered (would be good addition to ruamel.ordereddict to recognise collection.OrderedDicts)):

```
from ruamel.ordereddict import ordereddict

q = ordereddict(o, relax=True)
print q[1:3]
r = odict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
print r[1:3]
```

If you want (or have to) stay within the standard library you can sublass `collections.OrderedDict`'s `__getitem__`:

```
class SlicableOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if not isinstance(k, slice):
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, k)
        x = SlicableOrderedDict()
        for idx, key in enumerate(self.keys()):
            if k.start <= idx < k.stop:
                x[key] = self[key]
        return x

s = SlicableOrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
print s[1:3]
```

of course you could use Martijn's or Jimmy's shorter versions to get the actual slice that needs returning:

```
from itertools import islice
class SlicableOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if not isinstance(k, slice):
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, k)
        return SlicableOrderedDict(islice(self.viewitems(), k.start, k.stop))

t = SlicableOrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
print t[1:3]
```

or if you just want smarten up all existing `OrderedDict`s without subclassing:

```
def get_item(self, k):
    if not isinstance(k, slice):
        return OrderedDict._old__getitem__(self, k)
    return OrderedDict(islice(self.viewitems(), k.start, k.stop))

OrderedDict._old__getitem__ = OrderedDict.__getitem__
OrderedDict.__getitem__ = get_item

u = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
print u[1:3]
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks!  Note that the SlicableOrderedDict does not support negative indices as written.

Comment: I get an error: 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' when using odict package

Comment: Also, changing the built-in __getitem__ implementation (without subclassing) yields in 'TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'collections.OrderedDict' (for subclassing example change self.viewitems() to self.items() for python 3.x)

Answer (score 18):

You can use the `itertools.islice` function, which takes an iterable and outputs the `stop` first elements. This is beneficial since iterables don't support the common slicing method, and you won't need to create the whole `items` list from the OrderedDict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import islice
o = OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
sliced = islice(o.items(), 3)  # o.iteritems() in Python 2.7 is o.items() in Python 3
sliced_o = OrderedDict(sliced)
```

Comment: Is this O(n)? it seems like this operation needn't be.

Comment: In Python 3.7, I get the error `collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'iteritems`

Comment: Use `o.items()` in Python 3.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2, you can slice the *keys*:

```
x.keys()[1:3]
```

and to support both Python 2 and Python 3, you'd convert to a list first:

```
list(k)[1:3]
```

The Python 2 `OrderedDict.keys()` implementation does exactly that.

In both cases you are given a list of keys in correct order. If creating a whole list first is an issue, you can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and convert the iterable it produces to a list:

```
from itertools import islice

list(islice(x, 1, 3))
```

All of the above also can be applied to the items; use `dict.viewitems()` in Python 2 to get the same iteration behaviour as Python 3 `dict.items()` provides. You can pass the `islice()` object straight to another `OrderedDict()` in this case:

```
OrderedDict(islice(x.items(), 1, 3))  # x.viewitems() in Python 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to slice an OrderedDict using the following:

```
list(myordereddict.values())[start:stop]
```

I didn't test the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to slice using a key, since I didn't know the index in advance:

```
o = OrderedDict(zip(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),range(1,27)))

stop = o.keys().index('e')           # -> 4
OrderedDict(islice(o.items(),stop))  # -> OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

or to slice from `start` to `stop`:

```
start = o.keys().index('c')                    # -> 2
stop = o.keys().index('e')                     # -> 4
OrderedDict(islice(o.iteritems(),start,stop))  # -> OrderedDict([('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def slice_odict(odict, start=None, end=None):
    return OrderedDict([
        (k,v) for (k,v) in odict.items() 
        if k in list(odict.keys())[start:end]
    ])
```

This allows for:

```
>>> x = OrderedDict([('a',1), ('b',2), ('c',3), ('d',4)])
>>> slice_odict(x, start=-1)
OrderedDict([('d', 4)])
>>> slice_odict(x, end=-1)
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>> slice_odict(x, start=1, end=3)
OrderedDict([('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = OrderedDict(o.items()[1:3])
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30797178)

Comment: @SureshKumarVeluswamy: Why not? It's short. It should include more explanation. It might even be redundant with one of the other six answers. But certainly it's an answer.