# Get an object in a sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList using a different key

Tags: python, python-3.x, sortedcontainers

Let's say I have an Item with the following definition:

```py
Item(id: str, sequence: int)
```

*id* is a random string of characters.

*sequence* is the number representing the order that the `Item` was put into the data structure.

---

I wanted to organize all `Item` objects in some data structure that maintains the order of `Item` based on its `sequence`. So I used a [SortedKeyList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList) with they key set to `sequence`.

```py
import sortedcontainers

items = sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList(key=lambda x: x.sequence)
```

For most operations, this works fine. But the issue is that I have an operation that would need to get the `Item` with a specific `id`, but there is no way to do that using the key above.

I would like to do something like:

```py
items.add(Item('abc', 0))
items.add(Item('www', 1))
items.add(Item('zyx', 2))

# This should be the 2nd item added.
item = items['www']
```

---

*Additional info*:

The operation I intended to add would need to be able to return N number of `Item` starting from a specific `id`.

```py
load_n_items_from_id(num: int, id: str) -> [Item]
```

Using the example above, this method should return the following result:

```py
loaded = load_n_items_from_id(2, 'www')
# loaded should contain [Item('www', 1), Item('zyx', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question if I am not wrong is simply interested in maintaining the order at which I am inserting the element, if that's the case we can simply make use of built in function OrderedDictionary https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects rather than installing sortedcontainers via pip.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

items= OrderedDict()
#Items can be inserted according to your convenience either by loop or manually
items['abc']=0
items['www']=1
items['zyx']=2

print(items) #Prints dictionary in the given order
```

Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped, if anymore doubts, you may drop the comment. Infact I guess you can even use normal dictionary(Unordered) if all you want is the value of the corresponding key which you already have given while giving the input.

Comment: I've updated the question to provide more context. I tried using an OrderedDict, but from my understanding it does not provide a way to slice its contents in the way I would like. Similar to `List.slice`, I want a way to retrieve N number of `Items` from items starting from a specific id.

Comment: I still fail to understand your query. If you have elements inserted in order ["abc","wxy","lmn"] and then say you insert "pqr" at 4th position(1 based indexing), and if you want to retrieve the elements from 2 you can simply use l[2:](1 based indexing). You can keep on appending the element inside the list to maintain the order. Can you please be clear with more example or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Mukesh I'd look over these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975339/slicing-a-python-ordereddict

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```py
import sortedcontainers


class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, ident: str, sequence: int):
        self.ident = ident
        self.sequence = sequence

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Item id={self.ident} sequence={self.sequence}>"


items = sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList(key=lambda x: x.sequence)
items.add(Item("abc", 0))
items.add(Item("www", 1))
items.add(Item("zyx", 2))
```

To find the item will require O(n) complexity, because you are searching by something that it is not sorted by. Simplest way is to just search for the item, I like using `next` for this because it's the closest equivalent to a `find` with a predicate in python, and it's lazy:

```py
print(next((item for item in items if item.ident == "www"), None))
```

Gives:

```
<Item id=www sequence=1>
```

I would just throw it into a helper function:

```py
def find_by_ident(items, ident):
    return next((item for item in items if item.ident == ident), None)
```

Also, if the `SortedKeyList` is encapsulated, you may also be able to maintain a simple dict along-side it where `ident -> item` if you wish to have O(1) complexity here as well, but it may be no big deal or not worth the extra memory/code complexity.

Comment: I would like to avoid O(n) as much as possible. `sortedcontainers` might not be the way to go if I can't achieve this. I also would like to avoid adding a new variable with the sole purpose of mapping an `id` to an `Item`. I've updated the question with some additional details of the operation I intend to implement.

Comment: If the elements are not indexed and unordered (with respect to the key used) O(n) is unavoidable, is there a reason you wish to avoid an `id` -> `Item` mapping?